# Polymorphism on Realm (React Native SDK)

Tags: react-native, realm

I'm new to Realm and hit a bit of a snag when it comes to implementing a polymorphic design on a React Native.

Basically, I'm trying to figure out the best way to manage different entities that can all be involved in transactions.

We have the models `Transaction`, `Income`, `Wallet`, and `Expense`. A `Transaction` is always `from` someplace `to` somewhere. This could be:

- Income to Wallet
- Wallet to Wallet
- Wallet to Expense

I come from Django, where I would probably implement this with polymorphism, but Realm doesn't support that.

I've looked into a few options like using exclusive foreign keys for each entity type... But it feels... wrong.

What are the recommended pattern in this case?

Comment: The question is a little vague. Those are all Realm objects and you can create forward (and inverse) [relationships](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/relationships/) between them. You can also subclass if needed and/or [Model Inheritance](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/#model-inheritance). So.... what's the specific coding issue you're encountering?

Comment: I think inheritance is only supported on the Swift SDK. I've edited the question to emphasize I'm dealing with the React Native SDK where I don't think this is possible.

Comment: I see - that was just one option; there were others. I think we need to know what the use case is - what's preventing your code from working? You've got several models and those could easily be 'connected' through a [relationship](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/model-data/#relationships). What impact would polymorphic design have on the issue you're having? e.g. How would polymorphism correspond to Income and Wallet, which are two unrelated objects? How do you want to relate them? If you can provide more details we may be able to help.